# Why mysql event schedule not working in database localhost?

Tags: mysql, events

I had run : `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

My event scheduler script  is like this :

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE
DO
UPDATE customer_group
SET is_status = 1
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= end_date
```

It's not updating value in database localhost

Even though, in database server, it's an update

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked if the event scheduler is running? Try SHOW Processlist

Comment: @Adrian, `SELECT @@event_scheduler;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the following.

Issue a `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` or

```
select count(*) as theCount
from customer_group
where is_status=1 and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= end_date;
```

In other words, do some recon. Events succeed or fail silently as they have no user interface.

Run some commands like:

```
show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';
```

-- currently OFF (or it could be ON)

Specify the start time for your event during creation, and specify `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` such as

```
drop event if exists `Every_5_Minutes_QuestionUpdateImport`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `Every_5_Minutes_QuestionUpdateImport`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
    --
    -- all your statements go here
    -- 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Turn on the event handler:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;  -- turn her on and confirm below
```

Confirm it:

```
show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';
```

Examine the status of all events in a particular database by database name:

```
show events from stackoverflow; -- note stackoverflow is my database name
```

[image]

Disable or enable a certain event by name in the current selected db:

```
ALTER EVENT Every_2_Minutes_QuestionUpdateImport disable;
ALTER EVENT Every_2_Minutes_QuestionUpdateImport enable;
```

And last but not least, when I am writing a new Event, I always add initially in the event statements to log to a log table (with an insert statement and a datetime of `now()`). That way, I know it fired and that data in a where clause like yours perhaps is not giving me a wrong read on the whole thing.

And I mean I go crazy all over the place. Initially, then I rem it out later:

```
    set filename:=concat('c:\\datavault\\stackoverflow\\app01\\batches\\processMe_',LPAD(@idToPerform, 8, '0'),'.txt');
    set logMsg:=concat("It would appear I am to process this thing: ",filename);

    insert EvtsLog(incarnationId,evtName,step,debugMsg,dtWhenLogged)
    select incarnationId,evtAlias,10,logMsg,now(); -- 10: some step somewhere in the middle
```

Remember for all practical purposes (except maybe your table you really care about from your question) ... that `EvtsLog` of mine is your only user interface as an Events programmer and your best friend.

Look at the manual page for what [ON COMPLETION PRESERVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) means as well as other things.

Comment: @mosestoh this is a pure `mysql` routine. PHP does not play a role.

Comment: @mosestoh I will take a look. Please update it with any more total blocks of code if necessary as I only played with CI once for a raw query test. Meaning, I am a complete noob with it. But it does interest me. You can always ping me in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) room.